# Filtrar por otra tabla asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Holaa! estoy haciendo un proyecto que es un portal de empleo, donde el usuario puede revisar ofertas de trabajo, y así postular. Resulta que necesito mostrar las ofertas un filtro de otra tabla, dejo imagen de las relaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla AspNetUser es para loguearse en el sistema, y la tabla DatosUsuario, es para colocar datos del curriculo de la persona (curriculum vitae). Su relación es por el id.

Tengo un controlador, que me muestra todas las ofertas de empleo, dejo codigo:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.OfPostUsr_ID = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Email;
        ViewBag.OfPostOf_ID = new SelectList(db.OfertaLaboral, "Of_ID", "Of_Titulo");
        ViewBag.Of_Area = new SelectList(db.Area, "Area_Nombre");


        var asd = (from oferta in db.OfertaLaboral orderby oferta.Of_FechaIn descending select oferta).ToList();
        ViewBag.asd1 = asd;


        return View();
    }
```

Todas las ofertas las paso por un ViewBag que va a la vista. Ahora, lo que quiero mostrar son las ofertas de trabajo pero condicionadas a los campos de la tabla DatosUsuario (Educ_Sup, Jorn_Comp, Mov_Red y Tipo_trabajo). En simples palabras, necesito que me muestre solo ofertas bajo estas condiciones, pero no sé como llamar estas condiciones para que se muestren en la vista. Dejo vista:

```
@model ProyectoBase4.Models.OfertaPostulante

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Postulación";
var list = ViewBag.asd1;
}
@if (list != null)
            {
                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                    {
                        using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                               ....
```

Como se puede hacer? Alguna idea?

De antemano, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer un join en el Linq contra la tabla de usuarios y en el ON poner la condición de macheo.

Te dejo este link donde te explica como realizar los diferentes joins https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/sql-joins-with-csharp-linq

Comment: pero como tendría que ser? es que no entiendo mucho :/